# Replace the values of a given column in pandas with a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

So, I have a dataframe with the name of all the states in the USA and a few cities for each state. However, I need to change the names of the states to its two letter acronyms (ex: Nevada becomes NV and Wyoming becomes WY).

A have a dictionary with the name of the states/territories and its respective acronym, as you can see bellow:

`states = {'OH': 'Ohio', 'KY': 'Kentucky', 'AS': 'American Samoa', 'NV': 'Nevada', 'WY': 'Wyoming', 'NA': 'National', 'AL': 'Alabama' and on an on an on`

I was thinking about creating a new column, and once it was created, I'd drop the 'States' column. But my code bellow is filling the new column with NaN values

`state_town_df['acronym'] = state_town_df['State'].map(states)`

Is there any simple way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dictionary the key is `acronym` and the value is the `state`. I assume that `State` column is not an acronym. You may have to inverse the dictionary such as `inv_map = {v: k for k, v in states.items()}`